# How to add type hints to inherited descriptor classes in Python

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, python-typing, python-descriptors

I have a system of classes which allow hierarhical organisation of config files, based on descriptors. Problem is that Pycharm can't infer type of inherited descriptor `__get__` results, which should be the same as the class itself. I came up with a solution of adding explicit annotation to each inherited class, which makes code look dirty and I want to find alternatives. Here is a minimal example of a problem:

```
class Desc_A:
    var = 'Hello'

    def __get__(self, inst, own):
        print(self.var)
        return self.__class__()


class Desc_B(Desc_A):
    # My ugly hotfix that I want to ret rid of
    # Pycharm warns that expected return is of type Desc_A
    # noinspection PyTypeChecker
    def __get__(self, instance, owner) -> 'Desc_B':
        return super(Desc_B, self).__get__(instance, owner)

    var = 'World'
    var_other = 'hello_world'


class Container:
    a = Desc_A()
    b = Desc_B()


b = Container().b
print(b.var)  # Typing finds attribute
print(b.var_other)  # Can't find attribute if no explicit __get__
```

The solution i'm looking for is an annotation of base class's method is such a way that will provide corresponding type annotations to each of subclasses. I have tried to use `Generic` from `typing` module with no success, I hope that someone can help with it!

Comment: [PEP-673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) may be relevant. `Self` isn't yet available, but the PEP shows the workarounds that the use of `Self` is intended to replace. `def __get__(self, inst, own) -> Type[Self]:` is/will be, I think, the solution.

Comment: Maybe `Any` would suffice til `Self` is implemented. If so, you could put `Self=Any` somewhere in your script, and then just delete it when `Self` becomes available.

Comment: `from typing_extensions import Self`.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the type by "talking to the future" with the following code:

```
from __future__ import annotations  # must be at the the of the file

class A:
    def do_something() -> A:
        ...
```

Edit:

[PEP-563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/)